# Importing multiple Excel Data files into Tableau from multiple survey years

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to import data files from 3 different survey years into the same Tableau workbook. I'm working with survey data so I have to pivot the data to make it usable in Tableau. I'm also matching the data to a "helper" file that joins variables across years.

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

like Course Stacker said please next time do a better question.

I understood that your question is how to import multiples Excel files to Tableau and the answer is depends.

Are with the same structure? (means same numbers of columns for the excel data)
Yes, No, partially yes?

I will take the answer as partially yes to give you the both options:

If I have 3 files (Survey1.xlsx, Survey2.xlsx, Encuesta3.xlsx) and Survey1 and Survey2 has the same structure like the image:
[image]

Then you can create a datasource with Survey1.xlsx and over the Sheet select Convert to Union and use the Wildcard to select all the files with the same structure like :
[image]

And select the common name of the files in the wildcard like the image:
[image]

With the another file "Encuesta3.xlsx" create a second data source and you can use independ of the first one. If exist any relation, you can do a join.

[image]

About your issue with the years per each one of the surveys, (coming from the comments), It is really difficult to answer you without a clear question and without example of your data, but I am trying to do best to help you.

There are two options, one can be if you have a date column you can use it to create a new field as Year([Date]) or Year({Max([Date])})

If you don't have a date column or similar, then another thing that you can use is the Path column that is created when you do a convert to union of file (see previous images). Then, you can create a calculated field using the names of the file to identify each of year like:

```
CASE [Path]
    WHEN "Desktop/Survey1.xlsx" THEN 2017
    WHEN "Desktop/Survey2.xlsx" THEN 2018
END
```

If the name of the file has a reference of the year, you also can use it to get the year using the string functions: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_string.html

Comment: I know how to import multiple excel files and yes they are the same structure. I have to pivot the numerical data. The issue is that I would like to create vizes that have data from multiple years, and the initial files do not have year as a variable. I was told not not add year to the initial file, but I don't know what do from there..

Comment: Hi, Nadja, I did an update of my answer please check it.